Complex (i.e., Imaginary) Probability
I’ve been doing some numerical approximation of probability distributions.  For continuous $\operatorname{PDF}$s (or $\operatorname{CDF}$s) greater smoothness can be exploited to achieve more efficient approximations (i.e., greater accuracy with fewer parameters).
In numerical analysis the extreme class of smoothness is often a set of functions that are analytic over some significant portion of the complex plane.  For example, the Discrete Fourier Transform converges like $O(1/n)$ for functions with discontinuities on the real line, but if the function is analytic on a strip about the real line (with a bounded integral around the boundary of the domain) then the same Fourier Methods will converge like $O(e^{-\sqrt{n}})$.  Similar exploitation of smoothness exists for orthogonal polynomials, Sinc-Methods, and some types of wavelet approximation.
I have examples where assuming that the $\operatorname{CDF}$ or $\operatorname{PDF}$ has an “analytic continuation” onto a region of the complex plane (i.e., strictly containing the original domain) yields significantly more efficient numerical approximations.
But this raises a philosophical question, to say that $\operatorname{PDF}(x)$ is analytic in some domain (of positive measure) implies that both $x$ and the probability density are complex valued.
For this to make sense do I need complex probabilities?
I think the answer is yes.  I’d like the answer to be yes.  For the functions describing a distribution to be analytic (i.e., over a non-trivial domain) the probabilities will have to take-on values over a non-trivial portion of the complex plane.  That is, the image of an analytic function over a non-trivial domain must be a non-trivial region.
But at some level I don’t know what this would mean.
I see papers on real valued probabilities of complex signals or complex waveforms but am looking for the concept of complex probability.

You do not need complex probabilities.  Your underlying model may be a complex Hilbert space, and the unit vectors u in that space determine a projection onto the closed one-dimensional subspace with spanning vector u. Projection onto that subspace yield the prob. measure that the expected value of the corresponding observable in the state represented by u occurs, which is <Pu,Pu>.  This is the idea underlying quantum mechanics as a probability theory.  Take a look at https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-quantlog/

I was aware of this aspect of quantum mechanics but lack depth in this area.  I’m not working on a problem that naturally looks like quantum state estimation but understand that it might be the same.  If the state $u$ is analytic it has a smoothness that allows it to be efficiently approximated.  But I imagined that $<Pu,\ Pu>$ may not have similar smoothness properties and may not be estimated even approximately as efficiently.  But if you’re pretty sure this is the right direction, I could read up on quantum mechanics.

You do not need complex probabilities to make sense to use analytic PDFs.  However, a perhaps good related question is:  For analytic continuation of a PDF or CDF can we sometimes make a meaningful interpretation of the function at complex p?

If your probabilities err on being complex, I don't see how standard quantum mechanics would help since its probabilities are always real, being the inner product of complex values with their conjugate. Or maybe that's an entry point to extend it with quaternion values with inner product getting complex?

Let me rephrase my  previous comment.  You do not need complex-valued probability measures.  What you're doing is, I believe, correct.  The QM paradigm is just a generalization of standard probability.  (If you want to interpret the dynamic model for your state vector as complex valued there is no harm in that; that's the QM model).  For modeling purposes it is a powerful tool simply because you get cancellations not possible w/o using a complex space.  I believe that's what you are seeing.

A slight variant of @DmytroTaranovsky's comment: Even though you need complex numbers to talk about analyticity (in a strip), you don't need to call them probabilities. The situation seems analogous to talking about the square of the distance of a point on the real line from the origin. That function, $x^2$, has an analytic extension, $z^2$, to the whole complex plane, but we don't call the extension "square of distance from origin".

I ended up asking the related question I mentioned:  Interpretations of analytic continuations of CDFs to complex probabilities.

Dmytro Taranovsky's question is a much better statement of my core question.  Comments are helpful

When you say "I have examples where ...", could you please give such an example?

Since the question did not end up being closed, I will give an answer extending the comments.  You do not need complex probabilities.  An analytic function might amount to probability on some of its domain, and be something else otherwise.
However, since we get analytic continuations, it is natural to ask whether the resulting values can reasonably be considered (in some sense) complex probabilities or are otherwise meaningful.  Since analytic continuation is a natural concept, I suspect that in some cases the values are meaningful/useful, and (inspired by this question) I asked this separately, Interpretations of analytic continuations of CDFs to complex probabilities.  However, there are good reasons for such meanings to be probability-distribution-specific rather than being a general "complex probability".
While CDFs are one-to-one for nonzero densities, their analytic continuations might not be, and even worse, they might be multivalued in that the value depends on the branch taken.  Moreover, an $ε$-change to CDF (or just $ε$-change to PDF on a bounded set) can (through large values of higher derivatives) have an unbounded effect on the analytic continuation of CDF, which is contrary to how probability works.
That said it is difficult to rule out a natural concept for complex numbers that for real numbers in [0,1] amounts to probability.  Quantum amplitudes are complex (though real quantum amplitudes are not probabilities).  Extrapolations of probabilities beyond [0,1] can be viewed as (signed) measures.  In nonstandard analysis, probabilities can be infinitesimal (though they are still ordered and additive).  And there is even a noncommutative probability theory.
